# How to provide extra datasource to JIRA plug-in during integration test

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I'm looking for a way of providing an extra data source that will be picked up while performing integration tests using the provided JIRA plug-in SDK.

At the moment my plug-in accesses a JDBC database which I define by configuring Tomcat in the following way:

Add to server.xml:

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
  driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" 
  maxActive="20" 
  name="jdbc/myDS" 
  password="password" 
  type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
  url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://sqlserver:/database" 
  username="username"/>
```

and this to web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>My Datasource</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDS</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

From my plug-in I can then access the database as follows

```
 Context initContext = new InitialContext();     
 Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
 DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/myDS");
```

This method works fine when using a standalone instance of JIRA, however integration tests that I run using the provided `atlas-integration-test` start an embedded version of JIRA and it is this embedded version I am having trouble configuring to use the extra datasource.

I have found the file which I think I need to add the resource to `entityengine.xml` but this appears to be regenerated every time the embedded server starts so any changes I add to this file are lost.

I've been following this guide:
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Writing+Integration+Tests+for+your+JIRA+plugin

and have found a similar thread on the Atlassian forums which remains unresolved: http://forums.atlassian.com/thread.jspa?messageID=257355500&tstart=0

How can I can configure the embedded version of JIRA to pick up my data source?

Comment: any updates for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question but I think it would go better over on answers.atlassian.com under a jira development tag. I know someone got a MySQL config working for integration tests, or perhaps just changed how the JIRA SDK was configured?